# Can't use Material components

Tags: angular

I am switching this up now for hopefully a more modular and better design, but still the same issue of the html file not being able to see the Material components.

What I have done is removed everything from app.module.
I have a shared component that imports and exports the Material components
I have declared the shared component in the datafile.module that also declares the datafile list component and html....

The hierarchy of the files is as such:

app/shared/edxMoaterailModule

app/datafile/datafile.module.ts

app/datafile/datafile-list/datafile-list.component(.ts and .html)

What I believe should work is not so how do I get my shared material module to be usable in the datafile-list component?

edxMaterailModule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule,  } from '@angular/material/card';
import 'hammerjs';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, MatCardModule, MatButtonModule],
  exports: [MatCardModule, MatButtonModule]
})
export class EDXMaterialModule {
}
```

datafile.module.ts

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { DatafileDetailComponent } from './datafile-detail/datafile-detail.component';
import { DatafileListComponent } from './datafile-list/datafile-list.component';

import { DatafileLoader } from './datafile-loader.service';

import { EDXMaterialModule } from '../shared/edxMaterialModule';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: DatafileListComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: DatafileDetailComponent }

];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [DatafileListComponent, DatafileDetailComponent, EDXMaterialModule],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  providers: [DatafileLoader]
})
export class DatafileModule { }
```

Comment: See this stackblitz and compare with your implemenations: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material

Comment: You seem to importing modules incorrectly. For example, `MatButtonModule`, would be imported like `import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/button';`. I'd recommend to review the documentation for Angular Material, fix your imports and see if that makes any difference as a very first step.

Comment: if your datafile-list-component is in another module, you'll have to export the angular material modules from app.module, or you import the related modules in your datafile list module

Comment: When I change from MaIconModule to MdIconModule, I get "Module '"../../../../../Source/Git/edx-ui/node_modules/@angular/material/material"' has no exported member 'MdIconModule'. Did you mean 'MatIconModule'?"

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's a problem with declaring of datafile-list-component: I don't see that you declare it somewhere. 
If you want the datafile-list-component to see Material components, you need to declare this component in the same module where the Material components are imported to, like that:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
import { EDXMaterialModule } from './shared/edxMaterialModule';
import { MatIconModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatMenuModule } from '@angular/material';
import { MatCardModule,  } from '@angular/material';
import { DatafileListComponent } from 'your-location';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, FlexLayoutModule, EDXMaterialModule
            , MatCardModule, MatIconModule, MatButtonModule, MatSidenavModule, MatToolbarModule, MatMenuModule],
  declarations: [DatafileListComponent] // <-- ADD THIS
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I's not necessarily should be a AppModule - the idea is that component declarations and Material modules imports should be in the same module.

Comment: I have changed my structure based on your approach but still no luck. I have updated my OP

Comment: @Synphony32 no you didn't. You declare DatafileListComponent in DatafileModule, but it has no imports of Material modules in it - therefore the component doesn't know they exist.